# CSS Media Queries - Having Trouble making it work

Tags: iphone, css, media-queries

I have the following CSS, including a media query for iphone users, that does not seem to work:

```
body
{
background: url('background.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:100%;
}

#tab
{
width:30%;
height:60%;
position:fixed;
background: url('tab.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:33%;
top:20%;
left:35%;
opacity:0.7;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) 
{
body
{
background:#1589FF;
}

#tab
{
width:30%;
height:60%;
position:fixed;
background: url('tab.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:33%;
top:20%;
left:35%;
}
}
```

The normal CSS works fine, but the design does not alter when switching to an iphone. Can anyone suggest why the above media query does not seem to be working? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think `max-device-width` should be `max-width`.

Comment: As @MuhammadTalhaAkbar says, no need for the `-device-`.

Comment: thanks guys, definitely where i was going wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)
```

try:

```
@media (max-width: 480px)

OR

 @media only screen and (max-width: 480px)
```

Comment: @media only screen and (max-width: 480px)  worked perfectly, thanks guillaumek :-)